# Finding a locations closest to another location

Tags: sql, geolocation, location

I have a PostgreSQL table of locations in the format `_id | xcoord | ycoord`
and need to find the x nearest locations to a given point. The database is relatively large and therefore I need to write a query that is as efficient as possible.

My current solution  is ordering by the distance using the Pythagorean theorem and using a limit clause.

```
select * from locations
order by sqrt(($1-xcoord)^2+($2-ycoord)^2)
limit $3
```

Unfortunately this solution calculates the distance for every element in the table which makes it unusable for large datasets.

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You should install Postgis extension

http://postgis.net/

Then you will have a lot of geographic function available and you can do query over large table in milliseconds.

Then create a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(x double precision, y double precision)
  RETURNS map.get_near_link AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    strPoint text;
    sRow map.get_near_link;
  BEGIN
    strPoint = 'POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')';

    with index_query as (
        SELECT 
            Link_ID, 
            TRUNC(ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(strPoint,4326), geom  )*100000)::integer as Distance, 
            ST_AsText(geom), 
            geom
        FROM map.mapfile S
        ORDER BY 
            geom <-> ST_GeomFromText(strPoint, 4326)
        LIMIT 101
    )

    SELECT i.Link_ID, i.Distance, v.geom into sRow 
    FROM 
        index_query i 
    ORDER BY 
    distance limit 1;

    RETURN sRow;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION map.get_near_link(double precision, double precision)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Using `<->` is a spatial index sorting by distance

You will have GEOMETRIC objects or `geom`

and can use `ST_Distance` to calculate distance between two GEOMETRIC

`ST_GeomFromText(strPoint, 4326)` create a `geom` object from a string